# Azure B2C Single Sign-On from iFrame

Tags: azure, iframe, azure-ad-b2c

I have 2 sites using Azure AD B2c for authentication.  One site is embedded in the other using an iFrame.  Independently, auth works fine for each, but when inside an iframe, the site is unable to access the login page because it disallows iframes.  I really just need SSO to work but I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

We already faced this topic and were not able to solve it directly. 
Right now / during preview this is not supported.

You really have to put your sign in / sign up web pages into B2C custom templates (to have your desired look and feel) and forward to the respective policies from your web site.